# Foundation navbar transition links

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I made in javascript navbar transition, so when i scroll down background color of navbar is changed. Everything works fine except navbar links, i made a new id for links but just first link changes the color and other are not.

```
    var topbar, containtogrid, menulink, yPos;
function yScroll(){
    topbar = document.getElementById('topbar');
    containtogrid = document.getElementById('containtogrid');
    menulink = document.getElementById('menulink');
    yPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if(yPos > 150){
        topbar.style.backgroundColor = "#484848";
        containtogrid.style.backgroundColor = "#484848";
        menulink.style.backgroundColor = "#484848";
    } else {
        topbar.style.backgroundColor = "#00A7B7";
        containtogrid.style.backgroundColor = "#00A7B7";
        menulink.style.backgroundColor = "#00A7B7";
    }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

This is the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEgVQy
I am using sass so that is why there is lot of css, just scroll down to end of the css.

Comment: Please add code to your question and make the bit.ly URL obvious.

Comment: I know :) just copy the most important part of you code to stackoverflow in a code element and then you can insert the codepen-link.

Comment: I eddited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I forked your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rajQyV) and made the transition work.

I will explain the steps that I undertook:

1. I removed the id `#menulink` from the navbar links. Please note that IDs can only be used for one element. That's also why you only changed the first link on your page.
2. I simply set the background color of the links to transparent in order to make the color change of the `topbar` visible.
3. I removed the JavaScript-code that deals with the elements that have menulink-IDs as I removed them in the HTML.

So in my codepen the transition works but for the perfect result you might also apply changes to the mouseover styles and the dropdown elements.

Hope I was able to help you!

Comment: So much thankful now, this was bothering me a lot, but i dont see where you edit the style?

Comment: ok i see, but when i turn it to sass what do i need to type in css just this? .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
 background: transparent;
}

Comment: i set links background to transparent but for me it is not working.

Comment: It is not only set for the <a> element but also for the <li> element.